# Netlify deploy node.js + React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, netlify

**HI!**

When netlify start deploy my project from github, Netlify write "Production deploy faild" or something else.

Logs :

```
5:49:44 PM: %
5:51:23 PM: curl: (56) GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection
5:51:23 PM: was non-properly terminated.
5:51:23 PM: Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.17.0/node-v10.17.0.tar.xz failed, trying source.
5:51:23 PM: grep: /opt/buildhome/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v10.17.0/node-v10.17.0.tar.xz
5:51:23 PM: : No such file or directory
5:51:23 PM: Provided file to checksum does not exist.
5:51:23 PM: Failed to install node version '10'
5:51:23 PM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
5:51:23 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
5:51:29 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
5:51:29 PM: Finished processing build request in 5m20.05692486s
```

When i use netlify package in my CMD all good with deploy.
What i can to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

if you noticed here on the logs:

```
5:51:23 PM: curl: (56) GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection
5:51:23 PM: was non-properly terminated.
5:51:23 PM: Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.17.0/node-v10.17.0.tar.xz failed, trying source.
5:51:23 PM: grep: /opt/buildhome/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v10.17.0/node-v10.17.0.tar.xz
```

it had an issue with the internet connection or you have a permission issue trace the log and every thing will be ok ^_^